# Line around header on mobile devices

Tags: css, ipad, mobile, line, zooming

My problem shows itself only on ipad and iphone (have no none-apple device at hand). On desktop there is no line visible around the top header. But when looking at the site on ipad there appears a black line around it. On google i found that this is called a pixel error. But none of the topics provided a solution.

Does anyone here can help me out? The line disappears when zooming in on the ipad but zooming is turned off on request of the client.

Problem can be seen here:
http://ottenvaneck.nl/architectuur.php?projID=1

Answer (score 0):

remove "background-color: white;" from .header .

i found this bug usually in emails . a border is added when different background colors / borders are used for joining div's

Comment: This does remove the lines.. but then my fixed header is transparent.. So that won't work.

Comment: hmm . from my test this was not a problem since the background was #FFF as well . you can try and wrap everything into a new <div> and add the background color there

Comment: ok . now i got it . i would remove position fixed from mobile . position fixed its been proved to be buggy on mobile . so its not reliable . read more about it here http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/